# Interest on Amount Exceeding CC Balance?

Tags: credit-card

Let's say my credit card payment is due the first of each month. As of Jan 1 2013, my credit card balance was $1000.

So, as I understand, if I want to avoid paying interest on this debt, I'd need to pay $1000 towards that debt by Feb 1, 2014

If I pay $1000 towards that debt on Jan 2, 2014 (during the re-payment period), but then charge $2000 on the card, will I face any interest for any balance exceeding $1000, i.e the balance, for the Feb 1, 2014 due date?

Answer (score 2):

In the US, if your *monthly* statement was issued by the credit card company
on January 1 and it showed a balance of $1000, then a payment must be made towards
that balance by January 25 or so, not February 1 as you say, to keep the card
in good standing. The minimum payment required to keep the card in good standing
is specified in your monthly statement, and failure to meet this requirement can
trigger various consequences such as an increase in the interest rate charged
by the credit card company.

With regard to *interest* charges, whether your *purchase* of $2000 on 
January 3 is charged interest or not depends entirely on what happened
the previous two months.  If you had paid both your monthly statements dated
November 1 and December 1 of the previous year *in full* by the their
respective due dates of November 25 and December 25, and the $1000
balance on the January 1 statement is *entirely* due to *purchases*
(**no cash advances**) made in December, then you will not be charged interest
on your January purchase of $2000 as long as you pay it off in full by
February 25 (the charge will appear on your February 1 statement). But,
if you had not paid your December 1 statement *in full* by December 25,
then that $1000 billed to you on January 1 will include

- purchases made during December
- finance charges on the unpaid balance from the previous month
- *plus* finance charges on the purchases made during December.

The finance charges will continue to accumulate during January
until such time as you pay off the bill in full (these charges
will appear on your February 1 statement), hopefully by
the due date of January 25. But even if you pay off that $1000
in full on January 25, your charge of $2000
on January 3 will start to accumulate finance charges *as of the
day it hits the account* and these finance charges will appear on
your February 1 statement.  If you paid off that $1000 on January 10, say,
then *maybe* there will be no *further* finance charges on the $2000
purchase on January 3 after January 10 but now we are getting into
the real fine print of what *your* credit card agreement says.
Ditto for the case when you pay off that $1000 on January 2 and
made the $2000 charge on January 3. You most likely will not
be charged interest on that $2000 charge but again it depends on
the fine print. For example, it *might* say that you will be
charged interest on the average of the daily balances for January,
but will not be charged interest on purchases during the February
cycle (unless you miss the February 25 payment and the whole
cycle starts all over again).

As a general rule, it takes two monthly cycles of payment in full
by the due date before one gets into the state of no finance charges
for new purchases and effectively an "interest-free" loan of $2000
from January 3 (date of purchase) till February 25 (due date of
payment).  Matters become more complicated when cash advances are
taken from a credit card which are charged interest from the day
they are taken but don't trigger finance charges on new purchases
or the so-called "zero percent balance transfer offers" are
accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer to this is: *Read the fine print on your credit card agreement.*

What is common, at least in the US, is that you can make any charges you want during a time window.

When the date comes around that your statement balance is calculated, you will owe interest on any amount that is showing up as outstanding in your account.

---

Example...

To revise the example you gave, let's say Jan 1. your account balance was $0. Jan. 3rd you went out and spent $1,000.

Your account statement will be prepared every XX days... usually 30. So if your last statement was Dec. 27th, you can expect your next statement to be prepared ~Jan.24 or Jan. 27.

To be safe, (i.e. not accrue any interest charges) you will want to make sure that your balance shows $0 when your statement is next prepared.

So back to the example you gave--if your balance showed $1,000... and you paid it off, but then charged $2,000 to it... so that there was now a new set of $2,000 charges in your account, then the bank would begin charging you interest when your next statement was prepared.

---

Note that there are some cards that give you a certain number of days to pay off charges before accruing interest... it just goes back to my saying *"the best answer is read the fine print on your card agreement."*